# What are rules for completely blank tiles?

Tags: mahjong

Few days ago I got a Mahjong set. The majority of tiles I could identify from standard rules, but there were 8 I could not.

- 4 of them are completely blank.
- Another four have same desing of 2 red hieroglyphs in brackets (well, 2 straight angles around them).

What are they needed for? What rules should I look for?

Usually “mahjong joker” leads to endless web games pages.

[image]

NB. Set already includes all clearly identifiable dragons and flowers/seasons.

Comment: Here's a theory: http://www.mahjongtreasures.com/blank-mahjong-tiles/

Comment: Are you able to share a photo with us of the red one?

Comment: Done, photo shared.

Blank tiles being extras does sound credible

Comment: Given you've already received and accepted an answer for the blank tiles, it might be worth asking the identity of the other tiles as a separate question.

Comment: @Srv19 The other tiles read 百搭 “a hundred uses”, as they are jokers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know some sets use a blank tile for a white dragon. The red one could be a red dragon.

[This page](https://www.chinasage.info/mahjong.htm) has a blank white dragon.

And according to [this page](http://www.mahjongtreasures.com/blank-mahjong-tiles/) (link provided by  L. Scott Johnson):

> There are blank tiles in other sets too, including Chinese Bakelite and Bakelite sets. These tiles were always a bit of insurance that a lost tile would not make the set unplayable: one of the other tiles could be adapted. These sets tend to have carved White Dragons, so these tiles usually remain stored in the case until needed.

So it can be spare parts too.

Comment: In the set, there are tiles with green rectangle with "P" inside which i believe are white dragons - and also red dragons as they are usually depicted.

Comment: @Srv19 the last paragraph of the linked page states they're spares. Toon, if you update your answer cribbing that paragraph, I think that would over all the options. Better than having two answers linking to the same page.